# multidimensional array, different ways to represent address of grid[22][0]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm currently studying c programming language's multidimensional array and pointers.

I got asked the following question

> Suppose you have the following declaration:
>
> `int grid[30][100];.`
>
> Express the address of grid[22][0] two ways.

The author provided the following answers

```
&grid[22][0] or grid[22]
```

I came up with

```
//notice for the second answer, I placed an address operator & at the front 
&grid[22][0] or &grid[22]
```

I tested out with the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int ar[2][3] = {
            {11, 22, 33},
            {44, 55, 66}
    };

    printf("%p\n", &ar[2][0]);
    printf("%p\n", ar[2]);
    printf("%p\n", &ar[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

and all three form printed the same value

```
0062ff30
0062ff30
0062ff30
```

So is the author's answer `grid[22]` and my answer `&grid[22]` equivalent? How could they be equivalent?

Comment: The address are equal, the data types are not. `&ar[2][0]` is an `int*`. `ar[2]` decays into an `int*` and `&ar[2]` is `int (*)[3]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you use `%p`, then you have to cast the values to `(void*)`,
because `%p` expects a expects a void pointer

```
printf("%p\n", (void*) &ar[2][0]);
printf("%p\n", (void*) ar[2]);
printf("%p\n", (void*) &ar[2]);
```

They all have the same address (because they are all at the same place in
memory) but they expressions are of different types:

```
&ar[2][0];
```

is a `int*` (pointer to `int`)

```
ar[2];
```

is an `int[3]` (array of `int` of dimension 3), but in the `printf` it decays into
an `int*` and then into a `void*` because of the cast.

```
&ar[2];
```

is an `int (*)[3]` (pointer to an `int[3]`, array of `int` dimention 2).

You can see that `int[3]` is an array when you use `sizeof` with which arrays do
not decay into pointers:

```
printf("sizeof &ar[2][0]: %zu\n", sizeof &ar[2][0]);
printf("sizeof ar[2]:     %zu\n", sizeof ar[2]);
printf("sizeof &ar[2]:    %zu\n", sizeof &ar[2]);
```

This prints (on my system, `x86_64`):

```
sizeof &ar[2][0]: 8         (size of an pointer)
sizeof ar[2]:     12        (size of an array `int[3]`)
sizeof &ar[2]:    8         (size of a pointer)
```

If you have this function

```
void foo(int *x)
{
    (void) x; // to silence -Wall warnings
}
```

then `foo(&ar[2][0])` is fine and `foo(ar[2])` is also fine because it decays
into a pointer. But `foo(&ar[2])` is not fine, you would get:

```
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:21:6: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘foo’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  foo(&ar[2]);
      ^
a.c:3:6: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[3]’
 void foo(int *x)
      ^~~
```

However for

```
void bar(int (*x)[3])
{
    (void) x;
}
```

`bar(&ar[2])` is fine.

And bear in mind, that if you print the value/access the memory with any of
these expressions, you would be accessing the data out of bounds. `ar` should be

```
int ar[3][3] = {
    {11, 22, 33},
    {44, 55, 66},
    {77, 88, 99}
};
```

Comment: Assigning any pointer type to a void* is legal; no need to cast just for printf().

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I have seen this advices many times from other high-rep users and the man page states `p      The void * pointer argument is printed in hexadecimal...`, so that's why I repeat that.

Comment: There's certainly nothing wrong with the cast, it's just extra typing.

Comment: I don't mind the extra typing if it makes the code 100% correct, if the cast were very long, then I'd probably ignore it.